# How programmatically change BIOS time setting?

Tags: winforms, wmi, bios

How programmatically change BIOS time setting? The code is to be included to C# Window Forms application to insure the BIOS setting is always UTC time. I tryed to find solution in WMI using Win32_UTCTime but failed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically change the BIOS time...through any normal means.

The BIOS is stored on an EEPROM that is independent of the operating system.  The only way to interact with it is through direct programs that write directly to the hardware.  The various APIs do not provide a method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing/manipulating the BIOS clock [read this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/02/224672.aspx). It explains why Windows relies on the clock tracking the local time. So you might want to stay away from changing it.

To do an actual change [see this example from on PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetSystemTime.html)

```
class Class1
{
    /// <summary> This structure represents a date and time. </summary>
    public struct SYSTEMTIME 
    {    public ushort wYear,wMonth,wDayOfWeek,wDay,
            wHour,wMinute,wSecond,wMilliseconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function retrieves the current system date
    /// and time expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpSystemTime">[out] Pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure to
    /// receive the current system date and time.</param>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static void GetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

    /// <summary>
    /// This function sets the current system date
    /// and time expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpSystemTime">[in] Pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure that
    /// contains the current system date and time.</param>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

    static void Main()
    {    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
        GetSystemTime(ref st);
        Console.WriteLine("Adding 1 hour...");
        st.wHour = (ushort)(st.wHour + 1 % 24);
        if (SetSystemTime(ref st) == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("FAILURE: SetSystemTime failed");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Setting time back...");
        st.wHour = (ushort)(st.wHour - 1 % 24);
        SetSystemTime(ref st);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand this approach modifies system time only, but BIOS time still be unchanged. Am I wrong?

Comment: Setting the time in Windows changes the BIOS time on my machine.

Comment: According sources you refer to, there is hardware Real Time Clock (I named it "BIOS time" as it set time with BIOS help) and System (Windows) time based on RTC with shifts indicated in OS, e.g for time zone. Windows API modifies the system (OS) time only. (Sorry if I understood anything wrong)

Comment: Yes, you are right - it changes both. After restart the system keeps changed RTC time, but System returns to previous value. I am not sure I understand how ithappens. Anyway, thank you.

Unfortunately specification requests to avoid Win API.

Comment: Perhaps Windows is configured to sync with a clock on the network or internet. Avoiding Win API when trying to change something so fundamental to the system is nearly impossible.